# Clear the contents of columns A to C except row 1

Tags: excel, vba

I want to clear the contents out of cells A2:C.

I have column names in A1, B1, and C1 that I don't want cleared.

```vb
Sub Clear_Contents()
Range("A2:C").ClearContents
End Sub
```

I get an error.

I can change the range to be "A2:C100" or any other hard coded number but I want to clear from A2:A, B2:B, and C2:C.

Comment: You can either find the last row with values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/find-last-used-cell-in-excel-vba or just set it to the last row on the sheet: `Range("A2:C" & Rows.Count).ClearContents`

Comment: `A2:C` is not a valid range reference in Excel.

Comment: Optionally, without concatenation: `Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, "C")).ClearContents`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way

```
Range("A2").Resize(Rows.Count-1,3).ClearContents
```